# What is the fastest Mask R-CNN implementation available

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, onnx

I'm running a Mask R-CNN model on an edge device (with an NVIDIA GTX 1080). I am currently using the Detectron2 Mask R-CNN implementation and I archieve an inference speed of around 5 FPS.

To speed this up I looked at other inference engines and model implementations. For example ONNX, but I'm not able to gain a faster inference speed.

TensorRT looks very promising to me but I did not found a ready "out-of-the-box" implementation for it.

Are there any other mature and fast inference engines or other techniques to speed up the inference?

Comment: Do you need Mask R-CNN? You may  check YOLOV3 or RetinaNet as those are one stage (no proposal phase), especially YOLO is pretty fast and for similar tasks. You can find some comparisons [here](https://medium.com/@jonathan_hui/object-detection-speed-and-accuracy-comparison-faster-r-cnn-r-fcn-ssd-and-yolo-5425656ae359).

Comment: I need Instance Segmentation...

Answer (score 3):

It's almost impossible to get higher inference speed for Mask R-CNN on GTX 1080. You may check [`detectron2`](https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2) by Facebook AI Research.

Otherwise, I'd suggest to use [`YOLACT`](https://github.com/dbolya/yolact) - (You Only Look At CoefficienTs), it can achieve real-time instance segmentation.

[image]

On the other hand, if you don't need instance segmentation, you can use YOLO, SSD, etc for object detection.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. I already looked at YOLACT and I find its architecture very cool (The paper is also very readable as well). The problem is that YOLACT's performance on our dataset is very bad compared to Mask R-CNN. That is why I have to use Mask R-CNN. And the problem is instance segmentation so YOLO or SSD would not work.

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV 4.5.0 with `DNN_BACKEND_CUDA` and `DNN_TARGET_CUDA`/`DNN_TARGET_CUDA_FP16`.

Mask RCNN with 1024 x 1024 input image

```
Device             | FPS
------------------ | -------
GTX 1080 Ti (FP32) | 29
RTX 2080 Ti (FP16) | 60
```

FPS measured includes NMS but excludes other preprocessing and postprocessing. The network fully runs end-to-end on GPU.

Benchmark code: https://gist.github.com/YashasSamaga/48bdb167303e10f4d07b754888ddbdcf

Comment: 7 FPS on GTX 1050 -- so it will definitely be higher on GTX 1080

Answer (score 0):

As @kkHarshit already mentioned it is very hard to speed up a Mask R-CNN any further.

The fastest instance segmentation model that I found is [YolactEdge: Real-time Instance Segmentation on the Edge (Jetson AGX Xavier: 30 FPS, RTX 2080 Ti: 170 FPS)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.12259).

It's perfomance is worse than Mask R-CNN or Yolact even but still very good.